# How can I specify the version of zip to use in bash?

Tags: excel, zip, powerpoint, unzip

---

### Background (not necessary to read)

I'm tinkering with MS office files for work (trying to figure out the quickest, easiest way to automate generation of arbitrary-length excel and powerpoint files). Since actual excel files are just zipped archives with .xlsx appended to the filename, I've been unzipping them, editing the xml, rezipping them, and seeing whether OpenOffice can still load them.

However, I've realized (after not too much such testing, thankfully) that, by default, the 'zip' command in bash (or, at least, on my mac) is zipping the files in a format that only requires unzip v1.0 to extract, but normal excel files are zipped in such a way that they require v2.0 to extract. I checked this is a problem by zipping and unzipping an excel file that I knew loaded normally, and then trying to load it. OpenOffice was displeased.

So, I know I need to make the file zip exactly the way excel does, but how to make that happen I'm not sure. I have zip version 3 on my computer, so hopefully if the zip/unzip release cycles are synchronized it should be possible, but I didn't see anything on the man page that immediately seemed to be the solution.

edit: 
And zip -9 (which zip -h helpfully says instructs zip to 'zip better') still only requires v1.0 to extract.

---

### Question:

How can I specify in bash that I want zip to zip a file in such a way that it would require unzip v2.0 to unzip?

Comment: Interesting: `zip --help`, `zip -h2` and `zip -so` do not reveal anything about Unzip v2.0.

Comment: Sarcasm duly noted. Can't pretend I don't deserve it... And so I guess now, thanks to me, it's happened. At long, long last someone has finally accidentally asked a stupid question on the internet.

Comment: No sarcasm at all.  It was a completely straight observation that when I ran `zip` with the options shown, with the `-h2` and `-so` not being obvious, there was still no information.  I didn't have time to do further research.

Comment: Ah. I thought you were pointing out that I should've done more research into 'unzip', which would be perfectly valid point. In any case, thank you for your commiseration and, however unintentional, your enlightening me to a logic error I perpetrated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often, the reason for an incompatibility between compressed files produced by different versions is the compression algorithm used. If the files were compressed with an algorithm that didn't exist in zip 1.0, that would cause the incompatibility you're seeing.

Look at the man page for your zip utility, see if there's an option to specify the type of compression to use. If there is, look at the existing files created from Excel, and find out what type of compression algorithm they're compressed with, and use that.

On my Linux system, zip reports "This is Zip 2.31 (March 8th 2005), by Info-ZIP.", and it does not have an option for specifying the compression algorithm. On my Windows system, [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) does have the option, and it looks like they do have a Mac version available, so you could try that if your zip utility doesn't support that option.

Comment: Thanks! I actually ended up deciding to go with the Apache POI API and forgo trying to recreate exactly Microsoft document standards (because they proved unsurprisingly quite frustratingly opaque), but I'm sure I'll have to deal with this/an issue very like this soon enough, so any help is, well, helpful. :)